# SqlException conversion to a custom Exception handler

Tags: .net, exception

I have an existing application which uses MS SQL stored procedures to enforce some business rules.  When an error is detected it is raised as an exception using RAISERROR back to my .Net application.

The .Net application can then use Try/Catch blocks to catch and exceptions and perform and business logic.  The problem is that there are several business rules validated in a single stored procedure.  Which could raise different exceptions.  What is the best way to capture these SQL exceptions and convert them to custom .Net Exception handlers.

For example my stored procedure may throw an exception for RuleA and RuleB.  In my .Net code I can only capture SqlException.  My custom error message for either RuleA or RuleB is returned in the SqlException inner exception.   I could parse the Message string but this is UGLY and if someone changes the implementation in the stored proc. my logic would not pick it up.

What is a preferred method to translate the generic SqlException into MyRuleAException or MyRuleBException?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally the way to do it is to define the error constants in your .Net code and then you can check the value in your exception handling code. You can use constants to make the code more readable, something like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents the error code returned from stored procedure when entity could not be found.
/// </summary>
private const int SQL_ERROR_CODE_ENTITY_NOT_FOUND = 50001;

/// <summary>
/// Represents the error code returned from stored procedure when entity to be updated has time mismatch.
/// </summary>
private const int SQL_ERROR_CODE_TIME_MISMATCH = 50002;

/// <summary>
/// Represents the error code returned from stored procedure when a persistence exception occurs (ex.
/// billing flag is invalid, child records exist which prevent a delete, etc.).
/// </summary>
private const int SQL_ERROR_CODE_PERSISTENCE_ERROR = 50003;
```

Then, you can handle the exceptions like this, and it makes your code much more readable and maintainable:

```
    if (e.InnerException is SqlException)
    {
        // verify exception code from SP and throw proper exception if required
        var sqlException = (SqlException)e.InnerException;
        if (sqlException.Number == SQL_ERROR_CODE_ENTITY_NOT_FOUND)
        {
            e = new EntityNotFoundException(e.Message, e);
        }
        else if (sqlException.Number == SQL_ERROR_CODE_TIME_MISMATCH)
        {
            e = new EntityTimestampMismatchException(e.Message, e);
        }
        else if (sqlException.Number == SQL_ERROR_CODE_PERSISTENCE_ERROR)
        {
            e = new EntityServicePersistenceException(e.Message, e);
        }
    }
```

This is about as clean as you can make it in my opinion, but it's still ok because you define the error codes in one place, so if anything ever changes, you just change the one constant.

And to raise the error, you can do something like this in T-SQL:

```
 -- record wasn't found, raise an error
 DECLARE @l_error NVARCHAR(1000)
 SET @l_error = 'Record with ' + @p_IdFieldName + ' = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), @p_id)
    + ' does not exist in table [' + @p_TableName + ']'
 EXEC sp_addmessage @msgnum=50001, @severity=16, @msgtext=@l_error, @replace='replace'
 RAISERROR(50001, 16, 1)
```

The 50001 represents the error number that will be in the `SqlException.Number`.

Comment: Looking into this a bit more it appears that the existing code uses msg_str in the SQL code to raise the errors, not msg_id.  According to the RAISERROR documentation "When msg_str is specified, RAISERROR raises an error message with an error number of 50000."   I guess we would have to switch the implementation in the stored proc to be ID based instead of string based.  Also looks like we would have to preload the error numbers into the database using "sp_addmessage" .

Comment: I think dcp is saying you should not define `msg_str` which would allow `msg_id` to be what ever you want.

Comment: @Jay - Abe is right, with the way I'm calling RAISEERROR, I pass the 50001, not the message string.

Comment: Thanks this seems to be the best way from my reading as well.  The only downside is that the errors have to exists in sys.messages.  There are several databases in my SQL instance.  It appears that if tried to standardize on this method there will need to be communication across all developers for all databases, which could be error prone.  Plus, sp_addmessage is currently locked down in my environment.  We'd have to have an admin load any error codes in advance and ensure the uniqueness of the numbers.  Good from the standpoint of a pattern to follow, bad = more work for the admin :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with dcp. The process requires you to generate list of constants and is bit long process to implement. But will be very easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify a `msg_id` when you raise an error?  If so I believe this could be found in the SqlException.Number member.  Then you could do an if/else on that.  I would just make sure to document it well in the stored proc.

**UPDATE:**

On closer inspection I think you might be better off specifying different error levels when you call RAISERROR and then check that level through the SqlException.Class member.  Example:

```
--Rule A
RAISERROR (N'Rule A violation.', -- Message text.
           10, -- Severity,
           1, -- State)

--Rule B
RAISERROR (N'Rule B violation.', -- Message text.
           9, -- Severity,
           1, -- State)

--Rule C
RAISERROR (N'Rule C violation.', -- Message text.
           8, -- Severity,
           1, -- State)
```

then in code:

```
catch(SqlException qex)
{
  if(qex.Class == 10){}
  else if(qex.Class == 9){}
  else if(qex.Class == 8){}
}
```

Comment: Only severity levels of 11 or higher cause code to leave a BEGIN CATCH block in SQL.  and only severitys of 0-18 can be used by people without a sysadmin role.  so that only leaves me with 8 (18-10) possible custom errors :(

Comment: Good catch, I didn't realize that.  Do you have more than 8 RAISERRORs in one stored proc?